# Two queries into one subquery

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I want to combine the following two queries into one query qith a sub query.
First Query:

```
Select Match_ref, WBE Into Match_ref_Confilct
From RAW_MWBE
where WBE="p" or WBE="n"
group by Match_ref, WBE
```

Second Query:

```
Select Match_ref, count(Match_ref)
from Match_ref_conflict
```

The goal of this is to end up with a list of match_refs that appear more than once and therefore have a conflict of information. 
I tried this with no success:

```
Select match_Ref, count(match_ref)
From RAW_MWBE
where Exists( Select match_ref, WBE
from RAW_MWBE
where WBE like "P" or WBE like "N")
group by match_ref, WBE
having Count(Match_ref)>1
```

Access SQL

Comment: Where to find the duplicates; only in p/n records or in all records? What do you call a duplicate; a match_ref appearing more than once or a match_ref/wbe pair appearing more than once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can greatly simplify what you want to do:

```
Select Match_ref, count(Match_ref)
from RAW_MWBE
where WBE in ("p", "n")
group by Match_Ref
having min(WBE) <> max(WBE);
```

This does not use `count()` because you appear to care whether "p" and "n" are occurring together (based on your query example).

Comment: This works great. I have to change my way if thinking.

Answer (score 3):

```
Select Match_ref, count(*) as cnt
From RAW_MWBE
where WBE="p" or WBE="n"
group by Match_ref
having count(*) > 1
```